# Grand Total In Shopping Cart using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, shopping-cart

i need a help in my problem. This is just a simple problem but i couldn't get it. All you need to do is to calculate the grand total of the shopping cart below the table. You just need to use javascript only, no jquery is allowed. Hope you guys can answer this simple problem. Thanks guys.

```js
 var products = [];
        var cart = [];

        function addProduct() {
            var productID = document.getElementById("productID").value;
            var product_desc = document.getElementById("product_desc").value;
            var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
            var price = document.getElementById("price").value;

            var newProduct = {
                product_id: null,
                product_desc: null,
                product_qty: 0,
                product_price: 0.00,
            };
            newProduct.product_id = productID;
            newProduct.product_desc = product_desc;
            newProduct.product_qty = qty;
            newProduct.product_price = price;


            products.push(newProduct);


            var html = "<table border='1|1' >";
            html += "<td>Product ID</td>";
            html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
            html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
            html += "<td>Price</td>";
            html += "<td>Action</td>";
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_id + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_desc + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_qty + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_price + "</td>";
                html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick='deleteProduct(\"" + products[i].product_id + "\", this);'/>Delete Item</button> &nbsp <button type='submit' onClick='addCart(\"" + products[i].product_id + "\", this);'/>Add to Cart</button></td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            }
            html += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;

            document.getElementById("resetbtn").click()
        }
        function deleteProduct(product_id, e) {
            e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                    // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
                    products.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        function addCart(product_id) {


            //Indentify the product and add it to new "cart" array
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                    var cartItem = null;
                    for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                        if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {//Already exists in cart, increment quantity.
                            cartItem = cart[k];
                            cart[k].product_qty++;//Increment by one only, as requested.
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (cartItem == null) {
                        //Every item in the cart specifies the product in question as well as how many of the product there is in the cart, starts off at product's quantity
                        var cartItem = {
                            product: products[i],
                            product_qty: products[i].product_qty // Start of at product's quantity
                        };
                        cart.push(cartItem);
                    }

                    break
                }
            }

            renderCartTable();

        }

        function renderCartTable() {
            var html = '';
            var ele = document.getElementById("demo2");
            ele.innerHTML = ''; //Start by clearng your table of old elements

            html += "<table id='tblCart' border='1|1'>";
            html += "<tr><td>Product ID</td>";
            html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
            html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
            html += "<td>Price</td>";
            html += "<td>Total</td>";
            html += "<td>Action</td></tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_id + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_desc + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product_qty + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_price + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty) + "</td>";
                html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Subtract Quantity</button> &nbsp<button type='submit' onClick='addQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Add Quantity</button></td>";
                html += "</tr>";
                 
                 var GrandTotal = parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty);
                 document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = GrandTotal;
                 
            }
            html += "</table>";
            ele.innerHTML = html;
        }



        function subtractQuantity(product_id)
        {
            
            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                    cart[i].product_qty--;//decrement by one
                }

                if (cart[i].product_qty == 0) {
                    cart.splice(i,1);//Remove from cart
                }
                console.log("Products " + JSON.stringify(products));
            }
            //Finally, re-render the cart table
            renderCartTable();
        }
        function addQuantity(product_id)
        {
            
            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                    cart[i].product_qty++;//decrement by one
                }  
            }
            //Finally, re-render the cart table
            renderCartTable();
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart Pure Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="order" id="order">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="productID">Product ID:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="productID" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="product">Product Desc:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="product_desc" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="quantity" name="quantity" width="196px" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="price">Price:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="price" name="price" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />
    <input type="button" id="btnAddProduct" onclick="addProduct();" value="Add New Product" >
</form>
<br>
<p id="demo"></p> <br/>
<h2> Shopping Cart </h2>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
 var products = [];
        var cart = [];

        function addProduct() {
            var productID = document.getElementById("productID").value;
            var product_desc = document.getElementById("product_desc").value;
            var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
            var price = document.getElementById("price").value;

            var newProduct = {
                product_id: null,
                product_desc: null,
                product_qty: 0,
                product_price: 0.00,
            };
            newProduct.product_id = productID;
            newProduct.product_desc = product_desc;
            newProduct.product_qty = qty;
            newProduct.product_price = price;


            products.push(newProduct);


            var html = "<table border='1|1' >";
            html += "<td>Product ID</td>";
            html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
            html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
            html += "<td>Price</td>";
            html += "<td>Action</td>";
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_id + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_desc + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_qty + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_price + "</td>";
                html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick='deleteProduct(\"" + products[i].product_id + "\", this);'/>Delete Item</button> &nbsp <button type='submit' onClick='addCart(\"" + products[i].product_id + "\", this);'/>Add to Cart</button></td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            }
            html += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;

            document.getElementById("resetbtn").click()
        }
        function deleteProduct(product_id, e) {
            e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                    // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
                    products.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        function addCart(product_id) {


            //Indentify the product and add it to new "cart" array
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                    var cartItem = null;
                    for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                        if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {//Already exists in cart, increment quantity.
                            cartItem = cart[k];
                            cart[k].product_qty++;//Increment by one only, as requested.
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (cartItem == null) {
                        //Every item in the cart specifies the product in question as well as how many of the product there is in the cart, starts off at product's quantity
                        var cartItem = {
                            product: products[i],
                            product_qty: products[i].product_qty // Start of at product's quantity
                        };
                        cart.push(cartItem);
                    }

                    break
                }
            }

            renderCartTable();

        }

        function renderCartTable() {
            var html = '';
            var ele = document.getElementById("demo2");
            ele.innerHTML = ''; //Start by clearng your table of old elements

            html += "<table id='tblCart' border='1|1'>";
            html += "<tr><td>Product ID</td>";
            html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
            html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
            html += "<td>Price</td>";
            html += "<td>Total</td>";
            html += "<td>Action</td></tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_id + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_desc + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product_qty + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_price + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty) + "</td>";
                html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Subtract Quantity</button> &nbsp<button type='submit' onClick='addQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Add Quantity</button></td>";
                html += "</tr>";
                 
                 var GrandTotal = parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty);
                 document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = GrandTotal;
                 
            }
            html += "</table>";
            ele.innerHTML = html;
        }



        function subtractQuantity(product_id)
        {
            
            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                    cart[i].product_qty--;//decrement by one
                }

                if (cart[i].product_qty == 0) {
                    cart.splice(i,1);//Remove from cart
                }
                console.log("Products " + JSON.stringify(products));
            }
            //Finally, re-render the cart table
            renderCartTable();
        }
        function addQuantity(product_id)
        {
            
            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                    cart[i].product_qty++;//decrement by one
                }  
            }
            //Finally, re-render the cart table
            renderCartTable();
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart Pure Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="order" id="order">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="productID">Product ID:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="productID" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="product">Product Desc:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="product_desc" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="quantity" name="quantity" width="196px" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="price">Price:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="price" name="price" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />
    <input type="button" id="btnAddProduct" onclick="addProduct();" value="Add New Product" >
</form>
<br>
<p id="demo"></p> <br/>
<h2> Shopping Cart </h2>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only edit `renderCartTable` function

```
function removeCart(index) {
    cart.splice(index, 1);
    renderCartTable();
}

function renderCartTable() {
    var html = '';
    var ele = document.getElementById("demo2");
    ele.innerHTML = ''; //Start by clearng your table of old elements

    html += "<table id='tblCart' border='1|1'>";
    html += "<tr><td>Product ID</td>";
    html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
    html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
    html += "<td>Price</td>";
    html += "<td>Total</td>";
    html += "<td>Action</td></tr>";
    var GrandTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        html += "<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_id + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_desc + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + cart[i].product_qty + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_price + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty) + "</td>";
        html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Subtract Quantity</button> &nbsp<button type='submit' onClick='addQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Add Quantity</button>&nbsp<button type='submit' onClick='removeCart(\"" + i + "\", this);'/>Remove</button></td>";
        html += "</tr>";

       GrandTotal += parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty);            

    }
    document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = GrandTotal;
    html += "</table>";
    ele.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: I've added button for you. Can you check again?

Comment: I got it on my own. Anyway, Thanks a lot Tien